# how to return index radio button value from children Stateful widgets to another stateful widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, radio-button, future

I need to pass the index value of 2 radio buttons from a children Stateful widgets to another stateful widget in the same page.
Then when value is returned, with `button` Calculate, i will choose between "multiply" or "divide" operation. I already set the `if` statement, but i cannot get the value from radio buttons.
Radio buttons are custom buttons called from main stateful class as `MyStatefulWidget()`.

Code looks like this

```
class calculator extends StatefulWidget {
const calculator({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<calculator> createState() => _calculatorState();
 }

 class _calculatorState extends State<calculator> {

  return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(... some code here....)
     
      ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
        _showModalBottomSheet(context);
        }, child: Text('Calculate'.toUpperCase(),style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),), 
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}

_showModalBottomSheet(context) {
showModalBottomSheet(context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    builder: (BuildContext context){
  return Container(
            child:
            MyStatefulWidget(),
          ),
   ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
            if (value == 1){
              multiply();
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => result()));

            }else if (value ==2){
              divide();
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => result()));
            };

          }, child: Text('Calculate'.toUpperCase(),style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                primary: Colors.green),
          ),
        ],
```

My MyStatefulWidget() class:

```
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
@override
State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();}
 
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
int value = 0;
Widget CustomRadioButton(String text, int index) {
return OutlinedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      value = index;
    });
  },
   style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
    primary: Colors.white,
    backgroundColor: (value == index)?Colors.deepOrange: Colors.white,
  ),
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Row(
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
   children: <Widget>[
     CustomRadioButton("Multiply", 1),
     CustomRadioButton("Divide", 2),
     ],
   );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass function callback to `MyStatefulWidget` and call that function with the index value when the radio button is pressed.

```
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(int)? onChanged;

  const MyStatefulWidget({
    Key? key,
    this.onChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}
```

and now onPressed of the button in your state, you can call this function with the index value

```
  onPressed: () {
    widget.onChanged?.call(index);
    setState(() {
      value = index;
    });
  }
```

Finally, pass function to onChanged in `MyStatefulWidget`

```
return Container(child: MyStatefulWidget(onChanged: (value) {
             // Now you can use this value
           }),
          )
```